# how to use a function when page is dynamically reloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, dynamic

For sorting a table, I use a tablesorter like below:

```
<div class="dynamic-content">
    <table>
      <!-- code goes here -->
    </table>
</div> <!-- this div reloads only -->

<script src="tablesort.js"></script>

$('table').tableSort();
```

The problem: the page is dynamically reloaded, so after an ajax call, it does not work anymore. 
How can I make this still work when page is dynamically reloaded?

Comment: I mean, when a page transfer happens, which is the same as a reload, just staying on the same page, the entire page is blown away and the DOM is created anew.  If you want that logic to continue to work, you're going to have to perform the initialization again.

Comment: JQuery DataTables has a "destroy" method for when you have to reload the table data. Does the "tablesort" API you are using have a similar option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is calling `$('table').tableSort();` once.

When the table data is changed by an ajax request you have to call this again.

For instance, if you do something like

```
$.ajax({
  url: ...,
}).done(function( data ) {
  // do something with data
  $('table').tableSort();
});
```

Comment: @mudrayakatusha keep in mind that if this is actually solving your issue, this your question subject is misleading.  You are not dynamically reloading the page.  You are replacing page **content**.  A page **reload** is a specifically defined action that is entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want or cannot listen on the ajax request that makes the changes then you can observe on the change to the dynamic div and sort the table again. you can use Mutation observer as mentioned here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver.

I also prepare a codesandbox to demonstrate https://codesandbox.io/s/w055v284r5